# Problem with new App in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django. I have created a new App called "Directorio" and now I need to validate the SQL.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Directorio(models.Model):
    n_site = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_db_ins = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    user_db_upd = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    user_system_ins = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    user_system_upd = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my settings.py INSTALLED APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'directorio'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

After this I'm trying to validade the SQL with the command:

```
python manage.py sql directorio
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 219,
 in execute
    self.validate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in
 get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\djangodir\directorio\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Directorio(models.Model):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\djangodir\directorio\models.py", line 6, in Directorio
    user_db_ins = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 545, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

I can't understand the errors, can someone give me a clue?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andre,

length is spelled as lenght in your code. Please check for typos.

```
user_db_ins = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
user_db_upd = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
user_system_ins = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
user_system_upd = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. What a great english that I have. Sorry for this dumb question. Best Regards,

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?